# BigQuery log router sink not updating automatically

Tags: node.js, logging, google-bigquery, bunyan

Here's my setup:

- I am using bunyan for logging in my nodejs server (https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-bunyan-quickstart)
- I have created a log router to route my bunyan logs to a BigQuery dataset as the sink
- My log router has a simple inclusion filter that filters the log entries that go into the BQ dataset

My problem: I am unable to figure out how to make my BQ dataset update automatically as new log entries continue getting routed to the sink.

My log router sink is visible here: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/router?project= with a "Last updated" timestamp.
I am certain that new logs have been created that pass the filter, but the "Last updated" time is unchanged and I don't see the entries in my BQ dataset.

I went to documentation and all the settings I could think of, but haven't been able to figure out a way to have the logs show up in BQ dataset automatically. Documentation says that ~1min delay is expected, but I don't see any new logs show up.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi cgodiggo, Does this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#managing_sinks) will help you for update the log router sink ?

Comment: Turns out I had added some new fields to the logs and that was not matching my BQ dataset schema. This was resulting in an error and the BQ dataset was not being updated.